# Retrieve tables based on COL_LENGTH in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to establish a query design that can search my whole database and identify which tables have both of my columns (say these are '*Column_1*', '*Column_2*'), and only present the tables where the COL_LENGTH doesn't match. This the following design I've made, but SQL wouldn't process it as '*Cannot call methods on nvarchar*'

```
SELECT SUBQUERY.TABLE_NAME
FROM 
(
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
WHERE
    T.TABLE_CATALOG = 'DB_Name' AND
    T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT T.TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        WHERE
            C.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG AND
            C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
            C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME AND
            C.COLUMN_NAME = 'Column_1')
    AND EXISTS
    (
    SELECT T.TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        WHERE
            C.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG AND
            C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA AND
            C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME AND
            C.COLUMN_NAME = 'Column_2')
) AS SUBQUERY
WHERE
COL_LENGTH(SUBQUERY.TABLE_NAME.Column_1, 'Len_Column_1') != COL_LENGTH(SUBQUERY.TABLE_NAME.Column_2, 'Len_Column_2')
```

Comment: From [the docs for `COL_LENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/col-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16): `This function returns the **defined length** of a column, in bytes.` Not the length of the data _in the column_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just start over and not use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` at all.

```
SELECT [table] = t.name, 
    c1name = c1.name, 
    c1type = concat(type_name(c1.system_type_id), '(', c1.max_length, ')'),
    c2name = c2.name,
    c2type = concat(type_name(c2.system_type_id), '(', c2.max_length, ')')
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c1 ON t.[object_id] = c1.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c2 ON t.[object_id] = c2.[object_id]
  WHERE c1.name = N'column_1'
    AND c2.name = N'column_2'
    AND (c1.system_type_id <> c2.system_type_id
     OR c1.max_length <> c2.max_length);
```

Here is an [example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_0EVRDf9).

Note that `max_length` is double when the type is `nchar`, `nvarchar`, etc. but it shouldn't matter for comparison purposes (because a difference only between `varchar`/`nvarchar` or even `nchar`/`nvarchar` should still be highlighted). Also it doesn't matter for `max` - those are both `-1` but it would still be returned by this query if one was `varchar(max)` and the other was `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: Thank you @Rhythm Was a Lurker for the generous answer. I am assuming this is actually bringing up the Max_Length of the column which is fine, but my goal is to compare the actual content length in them. I just realized my question isn't even worded correctly. 


Let me re-write the objective "I want to compare the actual length of 'Column_1' and 'Column_2', and if they don't match I would like to retrieve them along-with the table they're coming from."

Comment: @SaberTooth Yes, that is a different question altogether. You want to return the name of a table where _any row_ in that table has column_1 and column_2 with different lengths? What does it have to do with the metadata in that case? It doesn't really matter if INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS or COL_LENGTH says 200, that is the defined length of the column, not the actual size of the data _in_ the column. Please create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: you're absolutely right. That has nothing to do with INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Working on the correct problem now. Thank you once again!